# Dynamic Key Word Replacement with considering casing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement in which client provides json Like below.

```
{
          "2222": [
            {
              "Employees": "Resources"
            },
            {
              "get": "obtain"
            }
          ],
          "33333": [
            {
              "Employees": "Partners"
            },
            {
              "get": "receive"
            }
          ],
          "111111": [
            {
              "Employees": "Associates"
            }
          ],
          "ABCD": [
            {
              "Employees": "workers"
            },
            {
              "test": "take"
            },
            {
              "TEST": "TESTTING"
            },
            {
              "Test": "Workers"
            }
          ]
        }
```

I have to read the value from the json as per the ID and have to replace the first word with second word given in the json if the first word is present in my site at the load time. So i have written the below piece of code in js.

```js
function keywordReplace(idStore) {
         $.getJSON("keywordReplace.json").done(
           function(data) {
            dynamicData = data;
            $.each(dynamicData, function(key, value) {
             if (key == idStore) {
              $.each(value, function(keydata, valuedata) {
               $.each(valuedata, function(keydata, valuedata) {
                keyReplace(keydata, valuedata);
               });
              });
             }
            });
           });
        }
    function keyReplace(oldKey, newKey) {
     var re = new RegExp("//b"+oldKey+"//b", "g");
    
     $("body").children().each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(re, newKey));
     });
    
    }
```

But Now they have told me to replace all the words without considering case that have given in the json. Like in Json if they are replacing "Employees" with "Partners" so I have to consider all the case of the old word("Employess") and have to replace accordingly in the site. Means if "Employees" is in lowercase then replace it with "Partners" in lowercase and same goes for upper case and for camel casing also.

And in json they can have phases also to replace.

Answer (score 0):

var keywordToReplace = "Partners";
var replacingKeyword = "Employees";

1) check in for each loop if replacingKeyword.charAt(0) is in upper case then replace it with keywordToReplace variable otherwise if all characters in lower case then make keywordToReplace.toLowerCase().

2) check also with replacingKeyword.toUpperCase() == variable then all characters are in upper case and then replace it with keywordToReplace.toUpperCase()

3) For all matching old look alike characters you have to make sure your array consists of all possible look alike words in it for comparison

Comment: Here, in json I will get only the word that i have to replace. Means that if I got employees then i need to see where ever the employees are there in my site, that has to be replaced with partners and partners case should be according to the case of employees word present in site

Comment: yes you have to replace the keywords with that body loop that you have shown to us I have told you the cases for replacing the string the way you could achieve that's it.